# Can the QPropertyAnimation update interval be increased for ultra-smooth animation?

Tags: qt, animation, qt4

The new Animation Framework in Qt 4.6+ is based on QTimeLine which has 'void setUpdateInterval(int interval)' public function. Based on QTimeLine as well, QGraphicsItemAnimation could access this function, but the new animation framework classes (e.g. QPropertyAnimation) can't! Is the animation framework locked to the about 60 updates per second which corresponds to a pixel-by-pixel transition of 60 pixels on screen per second only (for QPropertyAnimation animating position property) or is there a way to increase this without reimplementing everything?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some hardware limitations and also some limits with how the OS/Qt handles some of the painting.  The Qt Main Loop has something to do with it also.

In my experience, double buffering and repainting only the regions that need to be repainted will give you the smoother animations that you are looking for.  Also make sure that your graphics are close to the size that you are actually painting them.  Increasing the interval of refresh won't help most monitors because they don't refresh faster than 60 Hz.

Here is a [link](http://www.qtforum.org/article/9534/fps-on-qt-opengl.html) that may be helpful.

Qt works hard to optimize and get the graphics to look nice on a lot of platforms, and I know that as they are preparing for Qt 5, that there are some more changes to how the raster engine works.

I've also seen a demonstration similar to what is discussed [here](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/01/11/qt-graphics-and-performance-the-cost-of-convenience/) in person where they showed the frames per seconds of refreshes they could get with painting tiles in a game.  Here is a link to a [video](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/videos/watch/graphics-performance-best-practices) discussing it.  It goes into tweaking the performance of Qt for a particular game implementation, and what helps and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for Qt 4.8:

```
// You need qt source code to access QUnifiedTimer for QAnimationDriver
// Alternatively, copy'n'paste only the declaration for QUnifiedTimer class.
#include <qt/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation_p.h>

...

// In the animation thread, set the update timing interval.
// The smaller the interval, the more updates and more CPU consumption.
int animationTimingInterval = update_interval_in_msecs_u_want;
QUnifiedTimer::instance()->setTimingInterval(animationTimingInterval);
```